# how can I write " ± s.e.m. "in latex?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

To have + and - sign together, I used math mode, but that did not work, as I only get s.e.m as output without the symbols before. The error message says "undefined control sequence, package inputenc error`

The code I used is this ($\±$ s.e.m.)`", any help?

Comment: General question ~ [How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-letter-from-a-math-alphabet-or-other-chara)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$\pm$` to print + and - sign together.